# Admin create order view selected configuration options on item list

Tags: magento2, admin-order-create

On the admin create order screen after selecting a product with configuration options, I want to show those options, at the moment it will only show the product title and sku.

The top part of the below image shows how it currently displays and the button half is how I would like it to display. With the size and colour changing depending on the option chosen. I have looked, but I am unable to see the size/colour in the html code of that page.

When the Configure button is clicked `order.showQuoteItemConfiguration(100)` that code fires and shows the different configuration options. I am unsure how that function gets the information or how to just pull the name of the option chosen.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Unfortunately not.